# Connecting to an Embedded Device over WiFi on Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Working on a project where I have to interact directly with an Embedded device to set it up.

I've completed the iOS version of the APP, but now I'm on to the Android side of things.  The embedded device goes into Access Point (AP) mode and I can see it in the list of WiFi networks available to Join when I bring up the WiFi settings screen on Android.

But if I try to connect to it, the connection shows up at the bottom of the list with a little ? mark symbol next to it and the word Disabled underneath it.

I interact with the embedded device by sending http post and get commands.  This is 100% working on iOS, but I have no clue as to why Android won't let me establish the connection to the embedded device.

I understand this isn't a programming question per se, but I'm not seeing this addressed anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error on the embedded programming side in regards to defining the name and connectivity of the network.  This was not an Android issue.  Thanks everyone.

The WiFi chipset was a Bluegiga chipset.  When the embedded device was setting up the SSID for AP mode, the embedded processor was including a null string character to terminate the string.  iOS seemed to be ok with it, but Android would not connect.  Once the embedded programmer changed the way he was setting the SSID, the problem cleared up.

Comment: I am working on a similar thing. Can you please guide me on few doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this question is not programming type question . as my experience may be this wifi network are not support WPS connection or if support WPS network and your device are connected but internet are not sharing you can simple restart you phone than try to connect again may be you problem are solve

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Rebooted both systems and same results.  The Access Point is listed (Again the access point does not provide internet access, just a connection so I can upload a couple of settings to it), but when I try to connect to it it says that the connection is Disabled and a little ? mark appears next to the Wi-Fi name.

Comment: can you please provide you're hand set model.

On more think .. are you setup an router or any WiFi internet provider connection to use you. if you setup home WiFi with router than you have problem with your router configuration . may be your router are not enable to sharing internet that's why you face this problem

Comment: I am running an Asus Memo Pad 7.  The embedded device I am trying to connect to does not provide internet access.  It is broadcasting an SSID.  I need to connect to it in order to provide it with a few pieces of information.  The embedded device does not have a proper user interface so we use the handheld app to connect to the device over WiFi and send it the SSID / WEP Password / and network token so it can join the homeowners regular WiFi network.  I'm simply trying to figure out why Android will not let me select the SSID of the embedded device and connect